# PHP JSON keeps reading null values for 2nd items in array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am new to PHP and I can not seem to read my 2nd value of my JSON file. My current JSON file as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jennifer",
    "PvPwins": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Johnny",
    "PvPwins": 10
  }
]
```

My code is as follows

```
$json = file_get_contents("JSON_Data.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$query = "INSERT INTO Test(name, PvPwins) VALUES (?, ?)";
$st = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $PvPwins = $row['PvPwins'];

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, "si", $name, $PvPWins); // edited to move this down
    echo $name. " " .$PvPWins. "<br/>";
    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
} printf("Error : %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($st));
```

I get the following output:

```
Jennifer 
Johnny 
James 
Error: Column 'PvPwins' cannot be null.
```

// edit - It prints out name fine but just refuses to read the PvPwins and it is wins in small W. I've checked before posting so no cigars yet...

Please help and thanks!

Comment: Case matters. You define a `$PvPwins` (lowercase 'w') variable but are trying to use `$PvPWins` (uppercase 'w').

Comment: bind_param should be inside the foreach because there is no variable $name $PvPwins before foreach .

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the help. I had a mistake with the table attribute name that I was trying to put in. PvPWins in my stmt_bind_param instead of PvPwins in my actual database table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to try this
    echo $name. " " .$PvPwins. "
";

Capital W in PVPwins....???
]

Is it that simple?

Comment: Yeah, its fixed. I made a mistake with the database attribute name. I was looking at the variable name when I checked

Comment: Was first to spot the variable name error (within 4 minutes of it being posted) and someone even marked me down for it..!..going to bed upset.....

Answer (score 1):

You are calling mysqli_stmt_bind_param at the wrong place. At that time, the two variables $name and $pvWins have not been defiend. Should be corrected as follows

```
$json = file_get_contents("JSON_Data.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$query = "INSERT INTO Test(name, PvPwins) VALUES (?, ?)";
$st = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
 // moved from here

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $PvPwins = $row['PvPwins'];
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, "si", $name, PvPwins);
    echo $name. " " .$PvPwins. "<br/>";
    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
}
```

Comment: You still have the case issue between `$PvPwins` and `$PvPWins`.

Comment: @jszobody well spotted, copy pasted on all instances, hope that fixes it

Comment: tried to move the code down but still having the same error. this editor does not allow me to paste the code.

I don't quite think that is the issue because it prints out the name fine but it just retrieves NULL values for the PvPwins.

Comment: modified original post, still having issues. Weird that it reads the first value and does not read the second. I tried parsing it in an online JSON viewer and it reads the file perfectly fine...

Comment: if according to your update, it's PvPwins instead of PvPwins, let's just chanage that and everything would be allright (updating answer)

Answer (score 0):

> When JSON Data is decoded into PHP.... it automatically get converted into a Native PHP-Object which can be accessed using the PHP Object Accessor: `->` except when Boolean `true` is passed as the Parameter to the `json_decode()` Function. Be aware of that first. Consider this:

```
<?php

    $json   = file_get_contents("JSON_Data.json");
    $data   = json_decode($json);
    $query  = "INSERT INTO Test(name, PvPwins) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $st     = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, "si", $name, $PvPWins);

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $name       = $row->name;        //<== USING -> (NOT [...])
        $PvPwins    = $row->PvPwins;     //<== USING -> (NOT [...])

        echo $name. " " .$PvPWins. "<br/>";
        mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
    } 
     printf("Error : %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($st));
```

**NOTE:** This Code does not assume to provide a Solution but rather point you to the fact that accessing `name` or `PvPWins` could be better done using PHP Object Accessor: `->` if the 2nd parameter to `json_decode()` be omitted.

Comment: Umm, no. The OP is using the second argument `true` in `json_decode` which _returns an associative array not an object_. You're doing this as well, which means your object accessor won't work. Try this code, you'll get errors.